# How to install MS SQL Server PHP driver (pdo_sqlsrv) on XAMPP from LAMP packaged by bitnami as EC2 app on aws amazon.com

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, lamp, bitnami, sqlsrv

I am doing a PHP app on my Windows PC. I installed XAMPP on my Windows PC and installed MS SQL Server driver for PHP and the PHP pages could communicate with the MS SQL Server database that is also installed on my Windows PC. The connection to the MS SQL Server database is created with pdo sqlsrv as follows:

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$serverName ; Database = $dbName", $userName, $userPassword);
$query=' update statement; insert statement; select statement;'; -- can contain multiple SQL statements
$getRes = $conn->prepare($query);
$params=array( if any;); 
$getRes->execute($params);
while($row = $getRes->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) {
--display results with echo statements to web page;
}
```

With pdo sqlsrv, $conn->prepare() can contains multiple SQL Statements at once. It works well on my local PC. Those multiple SQL Statements can be queries that use UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE commands and also could be SELECT queries. Those multiple SQL statements are included in prepare() and could return a result set for the last SELECT query which could be the last result of several SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE previous queries included in the same prepare(). This works perfectly because all these code are running on Windows OS on which XAMPP with PHP is installed with MS SQL Server PHP driver which is a DLL file.

I am testing the same app on the web hosting from AWS amazon.com. I added LAMP Packaged by Bitnami which includes XAMPP as an EC2 application on AWS. But I could not install MS SQL Server PHP driver on amazon.com that is linux 2 (?). Some posts say amazon does not support MS SQL Server PHP driver which is actually pdo_sqlsrv. I found the pdo_dblib shipped with LAMP package on AWS can connect to MS SQL Server with the following code:

```
$conn = new PDO("dblib:host=$serverName;Database=$dbName", $userName, $userPassword);
$getRes = $conn->prepare($query);
$query=' only one statement;'; 
-- $query can contain no more than one SQL statement, otherwise no result gets returned and with  no error message
$params=array( if any;); 
$getRes->execute($params);
```

This code above uses pdo_dblib, not pdo_sqlsrv. This code works on AWS amazon.com. But the problem is this pdo_dblib can only send ONE SQL statement at once, and could not send multiple SQL statements at once, which is different from the above pdo_sqlsrv method that is used on my local Windows PC. To make the PHP app work on amazon, I have to rewrite my queries to include only one SQL statement for each $conn->prepare($query) for pdo_dblib. This is unwanted and I want to know if I could install MS SQL Server PHP driver (pdo_sqlsrv) in PHP of LAMP Packaged by Bitnami on AWS amazon. It is not MS SQL Server ODBC driver, but is MS SQL Server PHP driver. They are two different things. The intended driver is on page: https://learn.microsoft.com/th-th/sql/connect/php/download-drivers-php-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

thank you

I want to know if I could install MS SQL Server PHP driver (pdo_sqlsrv) in PHP of LAMP Packaged by Bitnami on AWS amazon. It is not MS SQL Server ODBC driver, but is MS SQL Server PHP driver. They are two different things.